# Send input to executable using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an executable C code binary which asks for 2 inputs. And I want to write a python code which gives the input automatically. What i mean is when i run `python code.py | ./ones-and-zeroes`. It give inputs to the executable. I tried using `print(INPUT)` but it only works if the input asked in next line, not in same line. Here is [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrlSF.png)

As you can see in image, I want to give -1 as first input, and something in second input.

I tried:

```
print(-1)
print(something)
```

a bit more brief is- i wrote:
print(1)
print(2)
print(3)

it worked [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebHIO.png) because the input asked in new line
but it did not work for other executable because input is asking input in the same line.

i may not be clear here, sorry. I simply want to input: -1 in the first question(How long is your secret:) and input: test or some string in second question(Enter your secret:). However i want to do it using python code. not manually

Edit: I don't have the exact C code, however i managed to reverse engineer it and here is something which might help.

```
void getFlag(void)
{
    ushort secret_len;
    char your_secret[1936];

    printf("\nHow long is your secret: ");
    __isoc99_scanf(&DAT_0804a0dc,&secret_len);

    if(1927 < (short)secret_len) {
        puts("\nYour Secret is too long");
         exit(0);
    }

    printf("\nEnter your secret: ");
    getchar();
    fgets(your_secret, (uint)secret_len, stdin);
    puts("\nThe Enclave will shield your secrets!\n");
    return;
}
```

Thanks everyone for help :)

Comment: You need to call that C-code binary with pythons `subprocess` library such as : `subprocess.run("your binary executable -arg1 -arg2")`

Comment: You can use [`subprocess.communicate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) to "pipe" to the stdin of your C executable.

Comment: "I tried using print(INPUT) but it only works if the input asked in next line" No, it won't work at all (although the C program may not be written in a way that makes this obvious), because the stdout of the Python process has nothing to do with the stdin of the C process.

Comment: @Karl, they're using a Unix pipe to pass the standard output of the python script to the standard input of the program.

Comment: Ah, I see it now. So the first question is, exactly what total text needs to be put into stdin? Then it's a simple matter of figuring out how to use `print` to generate that text. But it's a little difficult to understand exactly what the C executable's requirements are, since we have neither its code nor any documentation.

Comment: Is the question really: how do I do multiple "prints" to standard output without putting a newline character between them?

Comment: Or maybe it really is a question of how to print multiple values in a single "print"?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I added a bit of code for reference. I do not have the exact code :(

Comment: @Malcolm No no, i may not be clear here, sorry. I simply want to input: -1 in the first question(How long is your secret:) and input: test or some string in second question(Enter your secret:). However i want to do it using python code. not manually

Answer (score 0):

If you know all of the information you want to print on a single line there are a variety of ways to format up the multiple values on a single line of output.  One option to get -1 and then the contents of the something variable on a single line would be to use "f-strings"

```
print(f'-1 {something}')
```

Basically you can put any python code into curly braces and its string representation will be substituted into the string, and then the entire string will be printed with a newline at the end.

If you want to do multiple prints to the same line because you don't know all of your output at once, you need to use sys.stdout.write and then include an explicit '\n' when you really do need to write the newline.

Comment: No no, i may not be clear here. I simply want to input: -1 in the first question(How long is your secret:) and input: test or some string in second question(Enter your secret:). However i want to do it using python code. not manually.

Comment: Your example code looks like it is expecting a newline in between the length number and the secret, so the two prints should work.  You should be able to run "my_script | their_program" and it should work.  It should do the same thing as running 'echo -e -1\nsecret" | their_program'.  If instead to get their program to work you need 'echo "-1 secret" | their_program', then the answer I gave would work.

Wait, I have another though.  Is the problem that you want to execute their_program from within your program, not connecting them through a command line pipe?

Comment: it worked. Your explanation was super helpful 

Answer (score -1):

I did not understand your problem well, but if you mean to use input and take a value in the same line, you can use this code

```
x=int(input("How long is your secret:")
y=input("Enter your secret:")
```

Comment: No this is not what i mean. Thanks Anyway :)